# Java threads output

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to know the output of this code:

```
  class s1 implements Runnable 
    { 
        int x = 0, y = 0; 
        int addX() {x++; return x;} 
        int addY() {y++; return y;} 
        public void run() { 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            System.out.println(addX() + " " + addY()); 
    } 

        public static void main(String args[])
        { 
            s1 run1 = new s1(); 
            s1 run2 = new s1(); 
            Thread t1 = new Thread(run1); 
            Thread t2 = new Thread(run2); 
            t1.start(); 
            t2.start(); 
        } 
       }
```

Comment: if you want to know the output then simply execute it.

Comment: You are creating two unrelated `s1` objects, are you expecting this to be shared?

Comment: Type names, by convention, begin with an upper-case letter; methods and non-constant variables begin with a lower-case letter. So `s1` as a type name does not conform to the convention. It's also too terse to be meaningful.

Comment: In addition to what @PeterLawrey said, there's no synchronization (whether via `synchronized` or other concurrency controls), so even if you did have a shared object, your code would not work correctly.

Comment: @LewBloch That should be the expected out come that one might be looking for ;), though I suspect one thread will run and complete before the other one starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will print to the console this for each Thread:

1 1

2 2

3 3

4 4

5 5

6 6

7 7

8 8

9 9

10 10

The messages will be mixed up between the messages of each Thread because they are running simultaneous.